# Creating a tuple pointfree

Tags: f#, pointfree

Can the function `createTuple` below be expressed pointfree?

```
let createTuple = fun v -> (v, v*2)

createTuple 2 |> printfn "%A" // (2,4)
```

Comment: Do you mean the `(,)` operator, like in Haskel/Elm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The F# library does not provide many functions for writing code in point-free style (mainly because it is not particularly idiomatic way of writing F#), so you cannot write your `createTuple` function using just what is available in the core library.

If you *really* wanted to do this, you could define a couple of helper combinators for working with tuples:

```
/// Duplicates any given value & returns a tuple with two copies of it
let dup a = a, a
/// Transforms the first element using given function
let mapFst f (a, b) = (f a, b)
/// Transforms the second element (not needed here, but adding for symmetry)
let mapSnd f (a, b) = (a, f b)
```

With these, you could implement your function in a point-free way:

```
let createTuple = dup >> mapSnd ((*) 2)
```

This does the same thing as your function. I think it is significantly harder to decipher what is going on here and I would never actually write that code, but that's another issue :-).